# Applying strptime function to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, strptime

I have a pandas DataSeries that contains a string formatted date in the form of:

`2016-01-14 11:39:54`

I would like to convert the string to a timestamp.

I am using the `apply` method to attemp to pass 'datetime.strptime' to each element of the series

`date_series = date_string.apply(datetime.strptime, args=('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

When I run the code, I get the following error:

`strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (18 given)`

my questions are (1) am I taking the correct approach, (2) why is `strptime` converting my args into 18 arguments?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
date_series = pd.to_datetime(date_string)
```

In general it's best have your dates as Pandas' `pd.Timestamp` instead of Python's `datetime.datetime` if you plan to do your work in Pandas.  You may also want to review the [Time Series / Date functionality documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

As to why your `apply` isn't working, `args` isn't being read as a tuple, but rather as a string that's being broken up into 17 characters, each being interpreted as a separate argument.  To make it be read as a tuple, add a comma: `args=('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',)`.

This is standard behaviour in Python.  Consider the following example:

```
x = ('a')
y = ('a',)
print('x info:', x, type(x))
print('y info:', y, type(y))

x info: a <class 'str'>
y info: ('a',) <class 'tuple'>
```