# Converting timestamp to epoch milliseconds in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like the below:

| epoch_seconds | eq_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1636663343887 | 2021-11-12 02:12:23 |

Now, I am trying to convert the `eq_time` to `epoch` seconds which should match the value of the first column but am unable to do so. Below is my code:

```
df = spark.sql("select '1636663343887' as epoch_seconds")
df1 = df.withColumn("eq_time", from_unixtime(col("epoch_seconds") / 1000))

df2 = df1.withColumn("epoch_sec", unix_timestamp(df1.eq_time))
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

I am getting output like below:

| epoch_seconds | eq_time | epoch_sec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1636663343887 | 2021-11-12 02:12:23 | 1636663343 |

I tried [this link as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951348/pyspark-milliseconds-of-timestamp) but didn't help. My `expected` output is that the first and third columns should match each other.

**P.S**: I am using the `Spark 3.1.1` version on local whereas it is `Spark 2.4.3` in production, and my end goal would be to run it in production.

Comment: So, yeah. How do I resolve this? Suppose I have a timestamp like `2021-11-12 00:00:00.000` so what would be its equivalent epoch milliseconds?

Comment: `t = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-11-12 02:12:23.887', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
`
`print(t.strftime('%s%f')[:-3])
`  I would do it this way

Comment: you can't hardcode milliseconds value in date..it should be like derived from epoch and again derived back to epoch from date

Comment: I tried converting your value of epoch_seconds to date and time using an online tool: https://www.epochconverter.com/ and found out that the last 3 digits , i.e.  the milliseconds does not affect the epoch value, Please try the tool out and let me know!

Comment: Spark 3.5.0 has an inbuilt function [unix_millis](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) which can be used to convert a timestamp value to number of milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: Glad! there is a direct inbuilt function for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`to_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html?highlight=to_timestamp) instead of `from_unixtime` to preserve the milliseconds part when you convert epoch to spark timestamp type.

Then, to go back to timestamp in milliseconds, you can use `unix_timestamp` function or by casting to long type, and concatenate the result with the fraction of seconds part of the timestamp that you get with [`date_format` using pattern `S`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.sql("select '1636663343887' as epoch_ms")

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "eq_time",
    F.to_timestamp(F.col("epoch_ms") / 1000)
).withColumn(
    "epoch_milli",
    F.concat(F.unix_timestamp("eq_time"), F.date_format("eq_time", "S"))
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
#+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+
#|epoch_ms     |eq_time                |epoch_milli  |
#+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+
#|1636663343887|2021-11-11 21:42:23.887|1636663343887|
#+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Your timestamp is not the same as mine. How come ?

Comment: @whatsinthename we aren't in the same timezone ;)

Comment: Ohh yeah! I forgot

Comment: +-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|epoch_ms     |eq_time                |epoch_milli|
+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|1636663343887|2021-11-11 20:42:23.887|16366633438|
+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
This is what I get after ms conversion, is `date_format` not working?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to do the timestamp conversion with only using `cast`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.sql("select '1636663343887' as epoch_seconds")
df = df.withColumn("eq_time", (col("epoch_seconds") / 1000).cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn("epoch_sec", (col("eq_time").cast("double") * 1000).cast("long"))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

If you do in this way, you need to think in seconds, than it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To convert between time formats in Python, the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` and `.strftime()` are useful.

To read the string from *eq_time* and process into a Python datetime object:

```
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-11-12 02:12:23', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

To print *t* in *epoch_seconds* format:

```
print(t.strftime('%s')
```

Pandas has date processing functions which work along similar lines: [Applying strptime function to pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797854/applying-strptime-function-to-pandas-series)

You could run this on the *eq_time* column, immediately after extracting the data, to ensure your DataFrame contains the date in the correct format

Comment: It is not giving milliseconds and if I don't get it my data pickup activity would mess up.

Comment: There isn't enough data in the eq_time column to give you milliseconds