# How to pass pandas column inside datatime

Tags: python, pandas

I want to parse a list or pandas column ex: 21/01/2005, 22/01/2005 and covert them to 21 January 2005. But I get this error: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {
            'date': ['21/01/2022', '22/01/2022']
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
datetime.datetime.strptime(df['date'], '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d %B %Y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to apply the `strptime`/`strftime` functions to each element in the column.

```
df['date'] = df['date']
.apply(datetime.datetime.strptime, args=('%d/%M/%Y', ))
.apply(datetime.datetime.strftime, args=('%d %B %Y',))
```

Alternatively, [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) will be more appropriate for your use case.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797854/applying-strptime-function-to-pandas-series) for more.

Answer (score 1):

The `to_datetime` is a useful command here:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame, to_datetime

data_dict = {"date": ["21/01/2022", "22/01/2022"]}

df = DataFrame(data_dict)

df["parsed_date"] = to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```